# BO XI 3.1 List of values prompt item description return item key

Tags: business-objects

I'm trying to define a LOV with Universe Designer that when used in a @Prompt shows the user the item description, but gives back the corresponding item key as result of user selection.

e.g. From a dimension table of countries with two columns as COUNTRY_ISO and COUNTRY_NAME, I would like to show COUNTRY_NAME values to user with @prompt, but get back the corresponding COUNTRY_ISO as return value of @prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using **Index Awareness**.  I'll describe the solution using the sample "Island Resorts Marketing" universe, but the concept should map to your specific need.

For this example, we'll create a prompt on the "Country" object in the "Resort" class.  The prompt will display the country names, but the condition will apply to the country_id field.

First, we need to identify the keys.  On the **Keys** tab of the Resort\Country object, add a new Primary Key using `Resort_Country.country_id` as the source:

[image]

(in your case, you'll do this on the COUNTRY_NAME object, using COUNTRY_ISO as the primary key)

Next, we create the predefined condition that will include the prompt.  Create a new Predefined Condition, named "Select country", with the following definition:

```
Resort_Country.country_id = @Prompt('Choose a country','A','Resort\Country',Mono,primary_key)
```

What we're doing is is applying the condition to the ID field (resort_country.country_id), but using the country *name* (the `Country` object) as the source.  Note the "primary_key" parameter -- this tells BO to use the PK from the referenced object.

Now to test.  Create a WebI report and select the "Select country" filter along with a field to display.  I chose Service Line:

[image]

I run the report and am presented with a list of country names.  I choose France, and I get a list of the Service Lines associated with France.  The SQL generated by this query, reflecting my prompt selection, is:

```
SELECT
  Service_Line.service_line
FROM
  Service_Line,
  Country  Resort_Country,
  Resort
WHERE
  ( Resort_Country.country_id=Resort.country_id  )
  AND  ( Resort.resort_id=Service_Line.resort_id  )
  AND  ( Resort_Country.country_id = 2  )
```

Note the very last line, which shows that the condition is applied using the ID, even though I selected the country name "France".

References:
 - [XI3.1 Designer Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/boexir31/en/xi31_designer_en.pdf) @Prompt info, starting on page 520
 - [Dave's blog](http://www.dagira.com/2007/10/26/index-awareness-part-i-the-basics/) on Index Awareness
 - [Dave's blog](http://www.dagira.com/2008/11/01/designer-xi-3-new-feature-extended-prompt-syntax/) on Index Awareness with prompts